# classname.run_async() call in python

Tags: python

I came across some python code of the following format.

```
class ProcessC(File):
    @classmethod
    def c_headers(cls):
        return ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

    def process_decodes(self, decodes):
        r = []
        c = {}
        m = ""
        #Add logic.



if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = ProcessC.run_async(log_files)

    ProcessC.process_results(results, l_path + r'\CTags')
```

In the `main` there is a call `classname.run_async`. I couldn't find any documentation related to that anywhere. What does that mean? Also which function in the class does it call?

Comment: What is the `File` class? You never define it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run_async` and `process_results` are not implemented in the code you have posted. They are however called on the class `ProcessC` which will work if those methods are inherited by the `ProcessC` class.

The code

```
class ProcessC(File):
```

means that the `ProcessC` class inherits the `File` class, which in turn might inherit other classes of its own. The methods you are asking about are implemented somewhere in that inheritance tree.

If you can find any documentation for the `File` class, check there.